# Fit the LSTM model in Python using Keras

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm

First of all, I have just stepped in deeplearing. And I want to use LSTM (in python, using Keras libraries) to solve the prediction problem.

I have read the **dataset** (25 observations) from csv and splited it into 2 parts called: **train** set (67% of dataset, 17 observations) and **test** set (33% of dataset, 8 observations).

I have changed **train** set into 2 set:

- trainX: [[obs[1], 0] [obs[2], 0] ... [obs[n-1], 0]]
- trainY: [[obs[2], 0] [obs[3], 0] ... [obs[n], 0]]

(with n is the size of **train** set (17 observations))

(i have done the same thing with **test** set)

So, I have 4 set named: trainX, trainY, testX, textY

Each set has the shape like [x[i], 0]

I have read some "Google" document that i need to reshape it, so i do something like this:

```
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
```

After 2 lines code, my trainX will be like [value[i], time_steps=1, value[i + 1]]

(time_steps = look_back = 1)

Then i print my shape to check how it look:

```
print(trainX.shape)
```

My shape is:

```
(15, 1, 2)
```

At last, before I make predictions, I need to fit the model so I do this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

(Actually, I don't know how to fit the model rightly, so it tell me the error).

It notice the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_0_input to have shape (None, 1, 1) but got array with shape (15, 1, 2)
```

Could you tell me the way how i can fit the model with my data sets?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in all CAPS is more difficult to read and understand. Posting it that way will not get you answers any faster, and it's really rude when you come here and SHOUT demanding attention. When you look at the other questions on the main page, they're not in all CAPS because that's not appropriate here. Please stop doing so. Thanks.

Comment: I am so sorry. I have forgotten the rule.

Comment: The shape of `trainX` (15, 1, 2) does not match the input shape of the LSTM (None, 1, 1). I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but this error could be fixed by changing `look_back` to 2, for example. However, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a LSTM with only 1 timestep.